# Finding upper sum using $n$ sub intervals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, summation, upper-lower-bounds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJFm8.jpg)I am asked to calculate the upper sum of $f(x)= 5-2x$, from $x=1$, to $x=2$ using $n$ subintervals.

Below is my working out, however, the answer is $2 + \frac1n$.

I will appreciate it if you could give me a hint, or anything. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You say the work is below, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

As the function is decreasing, the upper sum comes from using the left hand endpoint of each interval.  For $n$ intervals, that is $1, 1+\frac 1n, 1+\frac 2n \ldots 1+\frac {n-1}n$  The upper sum is then $\frac 1n(f(1)+f(1+\frac 1n)+f(1+\frac 2n)+\ldots f(1+\frac {n-1}n))$  That is an arithmetic series which you should be able to sum.

Comment: Sorry about the image problem, I have attached it now. So, using the image as a reference, is it correct to have x(i-1)=i/n? and them resume doing the sum that i carried out in the image?